# different levels of nested comments per page

Tags: comments, threading

I am working on a wordpress site that usually allows three levels of nested comments. But I would like for (at least) one specific page to allow only one level of comments => no nesting.

How can I do that?

edit: requested clarification:
I can identify this page by the used page-template.

Comment: Please take a look at the [faq] as plugin recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Okay, any different idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please hover over the voting arrows to get a hint on what is needed to ask a proper question. A guid on how to ask can be found in the [faq]. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not get the point. Regarding the faq I do not see, where I missed the "how to ask" section. I really do not want to be rude, I just want to understand, what exactly I did wrong. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: No problem at all. Every question needs a basic amount of research shown, which you did by adding the "i can identify the page by it's template" comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reference the [Codex entry for **`wp_list_comments()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments).

This function includes a `'max_depth'` parameter in its args array.

On the specific page in question, simply call:

```
<?php wp_list_comments( array( 'max_depth' => '1' ) ); ?>
```

If you need more specific help, please clarify your question to indicate how you would *identify* the specific page in question. By title/slug/id? By Page Template? Some other way?